# Selenium inside siblings

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to click further inside siblings in Selenium Webdriver? For example, here's the HTML:

```
<tr class="rich-table-row xx-datalist-even" onmouseover="Element.addClassName(this, 'xx-datalist-mouseover')" onmouseout="Element.removeClassName(this, 'xx-datalist-mouseover')">
    <td class="rich-table-cell xx-datalist " id="userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:j_id102" style="text-align:center; width:20px;">
        <img src="/static/images/graphics/status1.gif" title="Disabled" />
    </td>
    <td id="userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:col1" class="rich-table-cell xx-datalist">
        <span id="userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:author_id">2377</span>
    </td>
    <td id="userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:col2" class="rich-table-cell xx-datalist">seleniumtest2312</td>
    <td id="userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:col3" class="rich-table-cell xx-datalist">
        <span style="margin-right:3px">Test2312</span>
        Selenium
    </td>
    <td class="rich-table-cell xx-datalist " id="userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:col4" style="text-align:center;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:j_id111" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('userTableForm01',event,{'similarityGroupingId':'userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:j_id112','parameters':{'userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:j_id112':'userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:j_id112'} } )" />
    </td>
    <td id="userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:col6" class="rich-table-cell xx-datalist">
        <a id="userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:enable_link" href="#" style="margin-right:5px" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.getElementById('userTableForm01'),{'userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:enable_link':'userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:enable_link'},'');}return false">
            <span id="userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:enable_link_text" class="xx-datalist">Enable</span>
        </a>
        <a id="userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:edit_link" href="#" style="margin-right:5px" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.getElementById('userTableForm01'),{'userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:edit_link':'userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:edit_link'},'');}return false">
            <span id="userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:edit_link_text" class="xx-datalist">Edit</span>
        </a>
        <a id="userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:remove_link" href="#" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.getElementById('userTableForm01'),{'userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:remove_link':'userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:remove_link'},'');}return false">
            <span id="userTableForm01:usersTableData:264:remove_link_text" class="xx-datalist">Delete</span>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now, this is a much bigger table than shown, so there are a lot more tr's with more users. The ID's are all auto-generated and different each time, and I am trying to click the 'Enable'-link, though the only thing unique on the same row that I can use is the username `seleniumtest2312`, which has brought me to this:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='seleniumtest2312']/following-sibling::td[3]/span[text()='Enable']")).click();
```

But it just won't work (no such element).

If there are better ways of solving this issue I'll be happy to try them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last part of your XPath is a bit off :

```
following-sibling::td[3]/span[text()='Enable']
```

because `<span>` you're looking for isn't direct child of `<td>`. You can try this XPath instead :

```
//td[.='seleniumtest2312']/following-sibling::td[3]/a/span[.='Enable']
```

Comment: ... I am a shame to autoamted testing, but thanks a lot for finding the error :-)

Comment: What the"a" stands for?